# Exclude Duplicate or Exisisting Values in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have report like this:

[image: sample report]

I tried to remove the duplicate values in documentno as paymentno column using :

```
DELETE FROM c_payment pa USING (
    SELECT MIN(ctid) as ctid, pa.documentno 
    FROM c_payment pa 
    GROUP BY pa.documentno
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) b
WHERE pa.documentno = b.documentno 
AND pa.ctid <> b.ctid) documentno
```

but it's still not working, any other advice on what method should I use?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Errors? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: if i added () before delete it said syntax error near from

Comment: And if you remove the parentheses?

Comment: sorry for the late reply already solved by myself, im using ROW_NUMBER() instead of delete, cause it wont work in complex data.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the last closing brace together with the word `documentno`.

Comment: im using ROW_NUMBER() logic to solved it, cause DELETE or DISTINCT only work in simple table.

Answer (score 0):

By using sequence number logic will work for my case

ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY pym.c_payment_id ORDER BY pym.c_bpartner_id)
as seq_no, coalesce (ci.documentno, '-') as inv_no ,

instead of DELETE with or without subquery

DELETE FROM c_payment pa USING (
SELECT MIN(ctid) as ctid, pa.documentno
FROM c_payment pa
GROUP BY pa.documentno
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) b
WHERE pa.documentno = b.documentno
AND pa.ctid <> b.ctid) documentno